# When is a Delphi form actually visible to the user on Android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

The game that I'm developing does some pre-processing when first loading and I want to show the user a "loading %" to make it clear that the game is not frozen.

I am trying to do this by waiting for the main form to show for the user and then displaying an updating progress bar while performing the pre-processing.

For the pre-processing to work, I need two pieces of information:
1. The form is in it's final size (maximized across the entire display).
2. The form is visible to the user.

Here is a log showing the order of the form events being triggered as my game loads. Keep in mind that I'm not actually changing the form's size using code in any of these events:

```
FormCreate
FormResize, clientSize : 0x0
FormResize, clientSize : 0x0
FormResize, clientSize : 0x0
FormResize, clientSize : 0x0
FormShow
FormActivate
FormResize, clientSize : 360x640
```

Currently, I try to show the loading screen on the last resize (the one indicating the form is actually the size of the display), but at this point, the main form is still not visible (even after the FormShow and FormActivate) and I end up with the Android's default "gray gradient" screen showing until after my pre-processing code already finished, never showing the progress bar.

I tried calling "application.processmessages" after updating the progress bar, but it doesn't make a difference...

How do I detect when my main form is actually visible to the Android user?

[Update]
I created a small application to demonstrate this issue:
https://github.com/bLightZP/Test_Splash

Comment: It sounds like whatever you are doing when showing the progress bar is not allowing it to repaint. Please show what code you are using to display/update the progress bar

Comment: @DaveNottage I edited the post with a link to the sources of a sample application demonstrating this issue.

Comment: The "pre-processing" you mention should probably be happening in its own thread, making Synchronize calls back to the main thread, to allow the UI to be able to update, similar to this example: http://chapmanworld.com/2016/06/14/delphi-tip-fmx-update-a-progress-bar-within-work-loop/

Comment: @DaveNottage This is not the issue, even if I did it in a background thread, I have no idea if the form is actually visible to the user, so I can't know if the user actually sees the progress bar updates. I will try just to see if it displays at least some of the progress bar updates.

Comment: If you do it in a background thread, the form has a chance to become visible; that’s the whole point

Comment: I managed to make something palatable using a background thread as suggested, but I would still appreciate if there was a definitive answer to my original question

Comment: To answer the part about when the form is first visible, there may be no easy way, since the rendering routines are part of the implementation in the FMX.Platform.Android unit, and they do not trigger any events or send any messages that might be listened to. Beyond modifying that unit, one possible way might be to use Application.OnIdle when it is *first* called, however given what happened in 10.2 (when OnIdle wouldn't even fire), it's still far from "definitive"

Comment: @DaveNottage To finalize things, trying to perform layout/timage bitmap changes in a thread while the app is still in the process of loading triggered massive instability.  In the end, I managed to get it working (On Delphi 10.2.3) by using the first OnIdle event. Dave, if you submit this as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example illustrates using OnIdle, and also how it *should* be implemented.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
  private
    FShown: Boolean;
    procedure ApplicationOnIdleHandler(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
    procedure ExecutePreProcessing;
    procedure ExecutePreProcessingSynchronized;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  // Method 1: Use OnIdle to execute code when the main form is visible:
  Application.OnIdle := ApplicationOnIdleHandler;
  // Method 2: Use a thread to execute the preprocessing. Comment out the line above if using this method, and uncomment the line below
  // TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(ExecutePreProcessingSynchronized).Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationOnIdleHandler(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  if not FShown then
  begin
    FShown := True;
    ExecutePreProcessing;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ExecutePreProcessing;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 100 do
  begin
    Sleep(50);
    ProgressBar1.Value := I;
    Application.ProcessMessages; // <---- Not the best idea
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ExecutePreProcessingSynchronized;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 100 do
  begin
    Sleep(50);
    // Ensure UI updates happen in the main thread
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        ProgressBar1.Value := I;
      end
    );
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I would just like to make a note that for a splash screen to actually be seen, I had to use a combination of a thread being created in the "OnIdle" event.  Not using a thread will still not show anything and using a thread before the first "OnIdle" event will cause instability.

Comment: Note: The example I posted (when using a thread) doesn't cause any instability for me

Comment: You could remove the OnIdle handler when it has done the work, making it executing only once, no need for additional boolean flag.

Comment: @DaveNottage  I would like to clarify further that this solution isn't 100% reliable either.  In some cases even after an OnIdle even the form is still not visible.  In the end I choose to wait for 3 OnIdle events before trying to show a splash screen and while it works fine on a few of my test devices, I'm still not 100% certain it will work on every android device.

Answer (score 1):

How about BecameActive event (ApplicationEvent)?
Use this article, translate it with Google Translate
http://delphifmandroid.blogspot.com/2016/09/delphi-android.html

Starting app:

```
09-20 20:13:43.151: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormCreate
09-20 20:13:43.151: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormResize
09-20 20:13:43.151: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormResize
09-20 20:13:43.161: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormResize
09-20 20:13:43.161: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormShow
09-20 20:13:43.161: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormActivate
09-20 20:13:43.161: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: Finished Launching
09-20 20:13:43.221: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormPaint
09-20 20:13:43.231: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: Became Active
09-20 20:13:43.261: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormPaint
09-20 20:13:43.281: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormPaint
09-20 20:13:43.311: I/info(15893): FMX: Project1: FormPaint
```

Comment: This information helped me with another issue (detecting when an Android app is in foreground/background), but I tested it and the form is still not visible even after "Became Active" is triggered.